# Trouble controlling the AccessoryType

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Hey guys,
I have an table in which the user can tap on items to get a checkmark in the accessoryType

```
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
```

It all works just fine, however the problem is appearing when i want to delete a cell. I am unsure how I remove the cell's accessoryType when i am deleting it, since if i dont it stays in the table, and possible places itself on a row which had no checkmarks before.

Like this, if i am deleting the first box to the left.

[X] [O] [X] [X] --> [X] [X] [X]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're talking about dequeueing a reusable cell and seeing the accessory checkmark already set on it from a recycled deleted row.

Every time you configure a cell in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, just make sure you explicitly set its accessory type. That way it's never random.

You can clear it by setting it to `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone`.

Comment: this is correct, we often think of cellForRowAtIndexPath as a creation method.  we need to remember that most of the time we are getting a dirty tableViewCell where most all the state needs to be reset.